# Real time streaming from external camera

Tags: reactjs, nginx, webrtc, http-live-streaming

I recently started a small react application in which I'd like to stream from a video camera installed on a small board (raspberry like).

I'm having a bit of trouble deciding which protocol to use to display the video.

Is it even possible in a web app to display the rendering of a camera (not located on the client device) in real time?

So far I've tried using HLS (with nginx) and generating a test pipeline with gstreamer, but I always get a 5-6 second delay that I can't seem to reduce.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, it is possible to display the real-time rendering of a camera, not located on the client device, in a web application. However, achieving low-latency streaming can be challenging due to various factors including network conditions and the protocols used.

HLS (HTTP Live Streaming) is a popular streaming protocol for delivering video content over the internet. However, it is not designed for real-time streaming and typically introduces several seconds of delay due to its chunk-based nature. Therefore, HLS might not be the best choice if you require real-time video streaming with low latency.

To achieve low-latency video streaming in a web application, you can consider using WebRTC (Web Real-Time Communication). WebRTC provides a framework for peer-to-peer communication and is well-suited for real-time applications like video streaming. It enables low-latency and high-quality video streaming directly between web browsers.

To implement WebRTC video streaming with a camera installed on a separate board (such as Raspberry Pi), you would need the following components:

1. A web server running on the board (e.g., Node.js) to handle signaling and relay video data.
2. WebRTC libraries or frameworks on both the server and the web app (such as `simple-peer` or `socket.io`) to establish the peer-to-peer connection and facilitate video streaming.
3. On the client side, you can use JavaScript APIs (`getUserMedia` and `RTCPeerConnection`) to access the camera and display the video stream in the web app.

By using WebRTC, you can achieve lower latency compared to HLS or other traditional streaming protocols. However, it's important to note that achieving real-time streaming with minimal delay also depends on factors such as network conditions and server performance.

Implementing WebRTC for video streaming can involve complex configurations and setups. It's recommended to explore existing libraries, frameworks, or tutorials specifically tailored for WebRTC video streaming in a web application to simplify the implementation process.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. It looks like it's been a while since you've posted and may not be aware of the latest policies since your answer appears likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). As a heads-up, [posting of AI-generated content is not permitted on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831).

If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.